# Can we improve the sharing feature on the site blog?

Tags: feature-request, blog, site-promotion

I like our blog!

We have some great stuff on there, and the folks here obviously put a lot of work into each post, not only in the writing itself, but in the research, experimentation, photography, etc.

I get the feeling that our readership could be improved. Especially considering that the material really is worthy of more visibility. I've also seen several posts that I've specifically wanted to "like", "share", "+1", etc.

I see that we currently have a "tweet this" feature, but it would be nice to have a few more options. Specifically, I would like to see buttons for Google+ share/+1 and Facebook share/like.